# How to fix Operation Timed out - error 28?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, litespeed

I'm getting this error in the Query monitor. Because of this error, the WordPress admin panel speed has been reduced. Please tell me how to fix this?
I'm using the Google Cloud and Litespeed server. The API is working correctly but maybe it's a hosting problem.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Your image is too low quality for me to read. Note: Do not use third-party services for images. Paste your image directly in your question where text does not apply.

Comment: Hi @johnHanley, Please check now. I have attached a High-quality image of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried to check several settings with woo-commerce and Query monitor, this issue is possible due to the network latency. If your server is in the Asia region, the curl timeout happens easily. If we launch the server in the US region, no timeout issue.

Since 1000 milliseconds = 1 second is quite short, you might want to try the following method that I found from the Google search to avoid such issue, hope this helps.

- https://kb.mailpoet.com/article/311-curl-issue-28-timeout
- https://gist.github.com/sudar/4945588